# Should the て form or dictionary form be used in this relative clause?

Tags: grammar

> あの人は千の魔法を使いこなす最強の魔法使い

I took this sentence from a manga. in this sentence the noun that follows 使いこなす directly is not the one that it directly modifies but 最強. In such cases should the て form or the normal form be used? I am under the impression that if the word following it are nouns/ adjectives, it would be the dictionary form while if it's another verb it should be the て form. Is it correct?

Comment: If it were the て form, it would indicate a sequence of actions. By the way, by "the noun that 使いこなす follows directly" did you mean "the noun **that follows** 使いこなす"? 使いこなす is an attributive verb that modifies the head of the noun phrase 魔法使い. The fact that the head is also modified by another word doesn't change that.

Comment: yeah I meant the noun that follows it haha. Thank you for correcting me. Edited it now

Comment: @EddieKal So could the て form be used here as well? with different nuances? I thought that if the word that follows the noun is not the one being modified, the て form needs to be used.

Answer (score 2):

Here 魔法使い ("wizard") is modified by a no-adjective 最強の ("greatest"), forming a *noun phrase* 最強の魔法使い ("greatest wizard"). 千の魔法を使いこなす is a relative clause that modifies the following noun, and this "noun" can be a noun phrase having more than one word. Here, the relative clause modifies not 最強 alone but 最強の魔法使い as a whole.

- (千の魔法を使いこなす)→(魔法使い)
  (a wizard) ← (who has mastered a thousand spells)
- (千の魔法を使いこなす)→(**最強の**魔法使い)
  (a **greatest** wizard) ← (who has mastered a thousand spells)

You don't have to change the conjugation of 使いこなす because it is modifying a noun after all.